# Linux ubuntu: Determine what service/program is blocking ports

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have inherited a strangely setup server running ubuntu 22.04 and I cannot figure out what is blocking ports. iptables show nothing - just Chain Input policy accept. There is no ufw or firewall of any kind that I can see in services.

I know something is blocking ports, as I can stop existing services and server on there former ports OK. I just can't server on any other ports.

Is there any way to trace out what process would be consuming the packets? Maybe something in /proc/net or something?

Comment: Your post implies you are working as a systems administrator / this is part of your job. Learning the basics of how the systems you manage is a MUST (and so is learning how to ask questions effectively). While this site is useful for specific issues, you should really take time to work through some structured training. There are free courses on the internet. Although its a little dated https://rlworkman.net/howtos/rute/ is still a good starting point.

Comment: Why do you expect that something is blocking? If it's a port in use, then nothing else will be able to bind,  and you'll get a very clear error message.

Comment: `lsof -  :portnr` would show you the port in use and what program

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a service called “neonft” which seems to be some sort of custom version of nftables. I only figured this out by searching every /etc/ file for the ports I knew were open and managed to come across its config file.

Still have no idea if it’s possible to know what services are manipulating net?